# Chart.Object.Export Errors

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm getting random #70 Permission denied errors when running this macro code at `.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export`

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I've also tried changing the path of the save image to desktop and sometimes that works. Could there be a process somewhere that is locking up the folder it is being saved to?

```
Dim TempFilename As String
With ActiveSheet

        With .Shapes(MyChart)
            .Width = PicWidth
            .Height = PicHeight
        End With

        .Shapes(MyPicture).Copy

        With ActiveChart
            .ChartArea.Select
            .Paste
        End With

        .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TempFilename, FilterName:="jpg"
        .Shapes(MyChart).Cut

End With
```

Comment: What's the error message? That's much more understandable than an error number...

Comment: Error #70 Permission denied.